# In Corda, how can i create a sample commercial paper state for writing contract test as per the tutorial “Writing a contract test”?

Tags: corda

I am following the following Corda tutorial: https://docs.corda.r3.com/tutorial-contract.html

Can someone provide a sample implementation of the `getPaper()` function which is not implemented there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this works or not. Please someone confirms if this is the right way of doing it while building Commercial Paper Contract Tests

```
private companion object {
    val testIssuance = bigCorp.ref(111)
    val testPounds: Cash.State = 1999.POUNDS.CASH issuedBy testIssuance

}

fun getPaper(): CommercialPaperState {
    return CommercialPaperState(testIssuance, testIssuance.party, testPounds.amount , Instant.now()+10.days)
    }
```

Or the below is another more complicated way of doing it without using the Cash provided as part of Finance CorDapp shipped along with Corda 4

```
import net.corda.finance.`issued by`

private companion object {
     val bigCorp = TestIdentity((CordaX500Name("BigCorp", "New York", "GB")))
     val testIssuance = bigCorp.ref((("JoinKey").toByte()))
     val testAmount = Amount<Currency>(1000,Currency.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY))

}

fun getPaper(): CommercialPaperState {
    return CommercialPaperState(testIssuance, testIssuance.party, testAmount `issued by` testIssuance, Instant.now()+10.days)
}
```